# Is it possible to add a new button to the "New Message" window in Gmail?

Tags: jquery, email, gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets, outgoing-mail

I'm trying to integrate Gmail with a CRM and I need to attach files from there. I'm trying to find a way of adding a button to the "New Message" window which opens a jQuery modal window that allow me to select a document and attach it to the e-mail. I know that sounds crazy and I want to be sure that can be done.

Any ideas will be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to send attachments from your CRM using GMail? What CRM?

Comment: OpenText eDOCS, but I don't think that's relevant. I just need a way to add a button in the "New Message" window or something like that.

Comment: Does your CRM have an associated email address with each account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm doing this creating a Chrome Extension with the [Gmailr API](https://github.com/jamesyu/gmailr) and adding the button manually using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
This is appropriate if your CRM has email facilities you want to bypass in favor of the GMail interface
In GMail go to settings, "Accounts and Import", "Send mail as", "Add another email address you own"
Follow the wizard and when you want to attach a file or send an email via your CRM address, choose your CRM address in the "From" drop down that will contain your CRM address.

Method 2:
This method is appropriate if you want to use GMail as your SMTP relay:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en

Both of these methods will let you send an email via your CRM including attachments.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the functionality that I want. Take a look at the [Cloudy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cloudy-for-gmail/fcfnjfpcmnoabmbhponbioedjceaddaa) Chrome Extension. I want something similar but getting documents from eDOCS instead of DropBox, Facebook, etc.